# Expectation of product of four complex jointly Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> If $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are jointly Gaussian complex random variables then what will be the value of 
>   $$\mathbb{E}[abcd]\ ?$$

I found two formulas regarding this and I am confused which one is correct. Is it

> $$
> \mathbb{E}[abcd] = \mathbb{E}[ab]\mathbb{E}[cd] + \mathbb{E}[ac]\mathbb{E}[bd] + \mathbb{E}[ad]\mathbb{E}[bc] - 2\mathbb{E}[a]\mathbb{E}[b]\mathbb{E}[c]\mathbb{E}[d]
> $$ or $$
> \mathbb{E}[a^* b^* cd] = \mathbb{E}[a^* c]\mathbb{E}[b^* d] + \mathbb{E}[a^* d]\mathbb{E}[b^* c]$$
>   where $a^*$ is complex conjugate of $a$?

Here are the snapshots of the books where I found those formulas. 
For the first formula:

[image]

And for the second formula:

[image]

**Edit:** I found one more now:

[image]

Comment: The Dirac delta function is a limit of Gaussians. Plug the Dirac delta function with mean $1$ into the equation. The first equation gives $1=3-2$. The second gives $1=2$. Therefore, if either of these equations is correct, it's the first one. (Unless there are further constraints on the Gaussians that preclude the limit I'm using.)

Comment: 1=2. how is it correct??

Comment: It might be useful if you gave links to the formulas. It also would be ***very*** good if you gave us the hypotheses on these variables. Are these independent complex Gaussian random variables, or is their probability density jointly Gaussian? Do they have mean 0 or not? The difference between the two formula probably comes from a difference in what hypotheses are assumed on the random variables. So for the second formula, I expect the assumption is that the variables individually all have mean 0.

Comment: I have added the refrences from where I have added those formula.

Comment: The first formula is correct. The second one applies to a restricted class of gaussian random variables, described before equation (1.97). The third one is incorrect (the authors miscopied the term $E(a)E(b)E(c)E(d)$). For future reference, please remember the name [Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis'_theorem).

Comment: @Did  I have a doubt, as I searched about the second formula I found that it is for zero mean Gaussian random variable but my doubt is why it doesn't included the third term like first formula.