# Showing $E\operatorname{Tr}(AAA^TA^T)=n^3 + 2n$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with IID standard Normal entries.

1. What is the easiest way of showing the following?

$$E\operatorname{Tr}(AAA^TA^T)=n^3 + 2n$$

2. What is the value of the following as a function of $n$?

$$E\operatorname{Tr}(AAAA^TA^TA^T)$$

The first few values appear below:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  & \text{n} & \text{value} \\
  & 1 & 15 \\
  & 2 & 64 \\
  & 3 & 183 \\
  & 4 & 432 \\
  & 5 & 895 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Context: Terry Tao's [book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf)  under "2.3.4. The moment method"  has an involved derivation of upper bound for generic symmetric $A$, I'm curious if it can be made much simpler for Gaussian $A$.

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-gaussian-second-moment.nb)

Comment: I ran your code up to $n=7$ to get a large enough sample; the third order differences of `getThirdMoment[n]` are arithmetic with a difference of $24$ between them, so it appears the answer to (2) is $n^4+10n^2+4n+45$.

Comment: **Correction** since I used the wrong initial value; it should be $n^4+10n^2+4n$

Comment: Do you know the existence of a [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2038984/305862) for the expectation of the product of 4 gaussian variables ? It is called "Isserlis identity".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\Gamma_d$ be the set of paths of length $d$ in the set $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$. That is, each $\gamma \in \Gamma_d$ is the sequence of $d$ edges $(\gamma_0, \gamma_1), (\gamma_1, \gamma_2), \ldots, (\gamma_{d-1}, \gamma_d)$ where $\gamma_0, \ldots, \gamma_d \in [n]$. Here, we allow self-loops $(i, i)$, so that adjacent vertices in $\gamma$ need not be distinct.

Then by expanding the matrix product, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[ \operatorname{Tr}( A^d (A^{\top})^d)]
&= \sum_{\substack{\alpha, \beta \in \Gamma_d \\ \alpha_0 = \beta_0 \\ \alpha_d = \beta_d}} \mathbf{E}\left[ \prod_{e \in \alpha} A_e \prod_{e \in \beta} A_e \right],
\end{align*}

Now, for each sequence $E = (e_1, \ldots, e_k)$ of edges and for each edge $e$, define $m_E(e)$ the number of entries in $E$ that are equal to $e$, i.e., $m_E(e) = \#\{i \in [k] : e_i = e\}$. Then [Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem#Even_case) tells that

$$ \mathbf{E}\left[ \prod_{e \in E} A_e \right] = \begin{cases} \prod_{e \in [n]^2} (m_E(e)-1)!!, & \text{if $m_E(e)$ is even for all $e$}, \\
0, & \text{if $m_E(e)$ is odd for some $e$}, \end{cases} $$

where $k!!$ denotes the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). These observations turn the computation of $\mathbf{E}[ \operatorname{Tr}( A^d (A^{\top})^d)]$ into a pure combinatorial problems. However, I am not sure whether this allows us to easily produce a closed-form formula for all possible values of $d$.

**Case $d = 2$.** In this case, all the possible pairs of $(\color{#0094FF}{\alpha}, \color{#FF6B00}{\beta})$ such that $\alpha_0 = \beta_0$, $\alpha_2 = \beta_2$, and $m_E(e)$ is always even for $E = \alpha \sqcup \beta$ can be categorized into $5$ distinct types:

[image: classification]

Here, black dots represent *distinct* vertices, and the leftmost dot is the starting point $\alpha_0 = \beta_0$ in each of the diagrams. Hence, using the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) notation $(n)_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[ \operatorname{Tr}( A^2 (A^{\top})^2)]
&= (n)_1(3!!) + (n)_2 \left[ 3 \cdot (1!!)^2 \right] + (n)_3 (1!!)^2 \\
&= n^3 + 2n.
\end{align*}

**Case $d=3$.** In this case, it is harder but still doable to enumerate all the possible diagrams by hand. Indeed, by considering all possible "shapes" of $\alpha$ and then checking which $\beta$ can pair up with $\alpha$ to yield a configuration with $m(e) \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, we can tabulate all the possible combinations of $(\alpha, \beta)$ as

[image]

As a consequence, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[ \operatorname{Tr}( A^3 (A^{\top})^3)]
&= (n)_1 (5!!) + (n)_2 [8 \cdot (1!!)^3 + 3 \cdot (3!!)(1!!) ] + (n)_3 [6 \cdot (1!!)^3] + (n)_4 (1!!)^3 \\
&= n^4 + 10n^2 + 4n.
\end{align*}

Comment: I like the pretty graphs. I wonder if it can be adapted to get a formula. It appears that multiplying $n$ **different** $d\times d$ matrices, expected Frobenius norm squared is just $d^{n+1}$ (asked on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459694/expected-norm-of-a-product-of-gaussian-matrices))

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\operatorname{tr}(A^2(A^\top)^2)$ is of the form $\operatorname{tr}(BB^\top) = \sum_{ij} (B_{ij})^2$, thus the expectation is $\sum_{ij} E[(B_{ij})^2]$.

Fix $i,j$ and note that
$$E[(B_{ij})^2] = \sum_{kl} E[A_{ik}A_{il}A_{kj}A_{lj}] = \sum_k 
E[A_{ik}^2A_{kj}^2] + \sum_{k\neq l}E[A_{ik}A_{il}A_{kj}A_{lj}].
$$

- Case 1: $i=j$
  $\sum_k E[A_{ik}^2A_{kj}^2] = E[A_{ii}^4] + \sum_{k\neq i}E[A_{ik}^2]^2 = 3+n-1$.
  $\sum_{k\neq l}E[A_{ik}A_{il}A_{kj}A_{lj}] = 2\sum_{k\neq i}E[A_{ik}A_{ii}A_{ki}A_{ii}] + \sum_{k\neq l, k\neq i, l\neq i}E[A_{ik}]^4 = 0.$
- Case 2: $i\neq j$
  $\sum_k E[A_{ik}^2A_{kj}^2] = \sum_k E[A_{ik}^2]^2=n$.
  $\sum_{k\neq l}E[A_{ik}A_{il}A_{kj}A_{lj}] = \ldots = 0.$ (ask for details if unclear).

Finally,

$$E[\operatorname{tr}(A^2(A^\top)^2)] = \sum_{ij} E[(B_{ij})^2] = \sum_i(3+n-1) + \sum_{i\neq j}n = n(n+2)+n(n^2-n)=n^3+2n.$$

Remark: [Isserlis's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem#Even_case) may provide a different way of computing $E[B_{ij}^2]$.