# Computing $E[\|ABB^TA^T\|_F^2]$ for Gaussian $A,B$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with IID standard normal entries.

What is the value of the following expression as the function of $n$?

$$E[\|ABB^TA^T\|_F^2]$$

The first few values are below,

[image]

Computed using following Mathematica code:

```
Clear[a, A, b, B];
norm2[mat_] := With[{f = Flatten[mat]}, Simplify@Total[f*f]];
getNorm2[n_, expr_] := (
   rules = {A -> Array[a, {n, n}], B -> Array[b, {n, n}]};
   traceExpr = norm2[expr /. rules];
   dist = # \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[] & /@ 
     Variables[traceExpr];
   Expectation[traceExpr, dist]
   );
For[n = 1, n <= 4, n += 1,
 Print["n=", n, " ", 
  getNorm2[n, A . B . B\[Transpose] . A\[Transpose]]]
 ]
```

Related discussion is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4818479/998) using moment method, but the direct enumeration of all paths gets fairly unwieldy as the paths have length 8

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit tedious to apply [Wick's/Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem), but there are only 9 non-zero contractions.

Anyways, you can always ask Mathematica to do the computation for you:

```
Wick[x_Times] := 
 Block[{L = List @@ x}, 
  Sum[c[L[[1]], L[[i]]] Wick[Times @@ (Drop[L, {i}][[2 ;;]])], {i, 2, 
    Length[L]}]]
Wick[1] := 1

c[A_[i_, j_], A_[k_, l_]] := \[Delta][i, k] \[Delta][j, l]
c[__] := 0

rules = {\[Delta][a1_, a1_] -> n,
   \[Delta][a1_, a2_]^2 -> n,
   \[Delta][a1_, a2_] a3_ :> (a3 /. a1 -> a2) /; Not@FreeQ[a3, a1]};

res = Wick[
    A[i1, i2] B[i2, i3] B[i4, i3] A[i5, i4] A[i5, i6] B[i6, i7] B[i8, 
      i7] A[i1, i8]] //. rules // Simplify
Table[{n, res}, {n, 1, 5}] // TableForm
```

Which outputs the result
$$
\langle\operatorname{tr}(ABB^TA^TABB^TA^T)\rangle = 3 n^3 \left(n^2+n+1\right).
$$

Comment: That's pretty neat....trying to parse the Wick function in your code....I guess this should be adaptable to compute arbitrary moments like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820524/formulas-for-trace-expressions-like-operatornametraata-for-gaussian-a)?

Comment: Indeed, you could also compute that expectation value.

Comment: Can you help me understand what your Wicks function is doing? Or some pointers to related material?

Comment: Wick's theorem instructs you to construct all pairings/contractions. The `Wick` function works by recursively constructing these: With a sum over $i$, pair the first factor with the $i$th and multiply by all pairings of the remaining factors i.e. `Wick[Times @@ (Drop[L, {i}][[2 ;;]])]`. Finally, you replace the each pair with the corresponding covariance matrix i.e. a Kronecker delta.