# Formulas for Trace expressions like $\operatorname{Tr}(AA^TA)$ for Gaussian $A$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with IID standard normal entries and I'm given a sequence like $A,A^T,A,A,A,A^T$. How would I obtain the formula for $E\operatorname{Tr}(AA^TAAAA^T)$ in terms of $n$?

I've gotten a few [formulas](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-gaussian-second-moment.nb) by computing expectations for a few $n$ and extrapolating, but this doesn't scale beyond 6

[image]

Comment: are you looking for the expectations? Have you tried a generating function?

Answer (score 5):

We compute $\mathbb E[\operatorname{Tr}(AAAA)]$ to explain how those expectation can be computed. This is not a final answer to the general case, just a step toward it.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\operatorname{Tr}(AAAA)] &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i}(AAAA)_{ii}\right]
\\&= \sum_{i,j,k,\ell} \mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{jk} A_{k\ell} A_{\ell i}]\\
\end{align*}

Let us recall [the moments of a normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments), it is clear from the moments of the normal vector and since we have i.i.d. and standard distribution that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{jk} A_{k\ell} A_{\ell i}] =& \mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{jk}] \mathbb E[A_{k\ell} A_{\ell i}]\\&+\mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{k\ell}] \mathbb E[A_{jk} A_{\ell i}]\\&+\mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{\ell i}] \mathbb E[A_{jk} A_{k\ell}]\\
=& \mathbf 1(ij = jk)\mathbf 1(k\ell = \ell i) \\&+ \mathbf 1(ij = k\ell)\mathbf 1(jk = \ell i) \\&+ \mathbf 1(ij = \ell i)\mathbf 1(jk = k\ell)\\
=&\mathbf 1(i=j=k=\ell)+\mathbf 1(i=k,j=\ell)+\mathbf 1(i=j=k=\ell)
\end{align*}

Summing over $i,j,k,\ell$ gives $n+n^2+n=n^2+2n$ as you mentioned.

If instead we had transposed one of the matrices then similar decomposition gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\operatorname{Tr}(AAA^TA)] &= \sum_{i,j,k,\ell} \mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{jk} A_{\ell k} A_{\ell i}]\\
\end{align*}

Observe the reversed order between $\ell k$ and $k\ell$. Now
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[A_{ij} A_{jk} A_{\ell k} A_{\ell i}] =& \mathbf 1(ij = jk)\mathbf 1(\ell k = \ell i) \\&+ \mathbf 1(ij = \ell k)\mathbf 1(jk = \ell i) \\&+ \mathbf 1(ij = \ell i)\mathbf 1(jk = \ell k)\\
=&\mathbf 1(i=j=k) + \mathbf 1(i=j=k=\ell) + \mathbf 1(i=j=\ell)
\end{align*}

Summing those gives $n^2+n+n^2=2 n^2 + n$.

I believe this explains how to compute those moments by counting. It feels like there should be a way to generalize and have a formula for your general case, but it is a bit involved in combinatorics. This may be solvable by transforming this into a graph problem, but I couldn't figure it yet.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Very clear. (Small typo in the first equation: _{ii})

Comment: Also @Ben gave Mathematica code to compute formula more generically [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4820872/998)