# Value of $E_{A,y}[\cos(A^T y,A^{-1} y)]$ for Gaussian $A,x,y=Ax$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-matrices

For $d\times d$ matrix $A$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with IID standard normal entries and $y=Ax$, I'm interested in the the following quantity where $\cos(u,v)$ refers to [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity):

$$E_{A,x}[\cos(A^T y,A^{-1} y)]$$

It appears to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, in simulations, can this be proven?

Motivation: This justifies the use of transpose+line search to approximately solve linear equations

```
randn[dims__] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {dims}];
mat = randn[1000, 1000];
{d2, d1} = Dimensions[mat];
pinv[mat_] := Inverse[mat];

bs = 10000;
vecsIn = randn[bs, d1];
vecsOut = (mat . vecsIn\[Transpose])\[Transpose];
meanAlign[vec1_, vec2_] := 
  Median@MapThread[(#1 . #2/(Norm[#1] Norm[#2])) &, {vec1, vec2}];
Print["average cosine similarity: ", 
 meanAlign[(mat\[Transpose] . vecsOut\[Transpose])\[Transpose], 
  vecsIn]]
```

Comment: Is cosine here referring to $\frac{u\cdot v}{\|u\|\|v\|}$? This notation is not standard.

Comment: @whpowell96 indeed

Comment: To my knowledge, working with the distributions of inverses is really difficult. If $A$ is symmetric, there is a known distribution with a good amount of literature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution

Comment: Related post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181163/what-is-known-about-the-distribution-of-eigenvectors-of-random-matrices Again, if $A$ is symmetric this reduces the problem to the study of the eigenvalues, but there is less literature on inverses of nonsymmetric Gaussian matrices

Comment: @whpowell96 ok, found proof, it has to do with ratio of Frobenius norms of $A$ and $AA^T$ converging to $1/\sqrt{2}$, not sure if it would be bad form to answer my own question here

Comment: answering your own question is fine

Answer (score 5):

You're right that this converges to $1/\sqrt{2}$ as $d \rightarrow \infty$.
In fact, we can explicitly find the distribution of your quantity of interest even for finite $d$.
Namely, if $X = \cos(A^Ty, A^{-1}y)$, then
$$
X^2 \sim \operatorname{Beta}\Bigl(\frac{d}{2}, \frac{d-1}{2}\Bigr),
\quad
\mathbf{E} X
= \frac{\Gamma((d+1)/2)}{\Gamma(d/2)} \frac{\Gamma(d - 1/2)}{\Gamma(d)}
\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$

To show this, write
$$
X
= \frac{x^T (A^T A) x}{\lVert A^T A x \rVert \lVert x \rVert},
$$
where $A^T A$ is a white Wishart matrix with dimention parameters $d, d$.
Now, the distribution of $A^T A$ is rotation invariant, so if we take $Q$ to bea an orthogonal matrix whose first column is $x / \lVert x \rVert$, then $W := Q^T A^T A Q$ is still Wishart and is still independent of $x$ (despite $Q$ depending on $x$).

But then we have that $Ax = \lVert x\rVert A Q e_1$, from which
$$
X
= \frac{x^T (A^T A) x}{\lVert A^T A x \rVert \lVert x \rVert} 
= \frac{\lVert x\rVert^2 e_1^T W e_1}{\bigl\lVert \lVert x\rVert Q W e_1\bigr\rVert \lVert x\rVert}
= \frac{e_1^T W e_1}{\lVert W e_1\rVert}.
$$

The problem thus reduces to finding the ratio between then $(1,1)$ entry of a Wishart matrix and the norm of its first column.

There's probably many ways of doing this, but one is using a result from random matrix theory known as matrix tridiagonalisation (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0206043.pdf) for a classic paper on the subject).
The upshot in this case is that there is an orthogonal matrix $U$ whose first and column are both $e_1$ such that
$$
W
= U^T \tilde{W} U,
$$
where $\tilde{W}$ is a matrix whose first column is $(A^2, AB, 0, \dotsc, 0)$, where $A$ and $B$ are independent Chi random variables with $A \sim \chi_d, B \sim \chi_{d-1}$.

But now, due to the special structure of $U$, we have that
$$
\frac{e_1^T W e_1}{\lVert W e_1\rVert}
= \frac{e_1^T U^T \tilde{W} U e_1}{\lVert U^T \tilde{W} U e_1\rVert}
= \frac{e_1^T \tilde{W} e_1}{\lVert\tilde{W} e_1\rVert}
= \frac{A^2}{\sqrt{A^4 + A^2 B^2}}
= \biggl(\frac{A^2}{A^2 + B^2}\biggr)^{1/2}.
$$

Now, since $A^2$ and $B^2$ are independent Chi squared random variables, there is a standard result that
$$
X^2
= \frac{A^2}{A^2 + B^2}
\sim \operatorname{Beta}\Bigl(\frac{d}{2}, \frac{d-1}{2}\Bigr).
$$

The expectation of $X$ then follows from an elementary integration.

Comment: Interesting technique. I wonder if it's possible to extend it to more general case of $X$ being product of $k$ independent Gaussian matrices, where corresponding quantity appears to converge to $1/\sqrt{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Below is proof outline. Several places switch the order of expectation $f(E(x))=f(E(x))$ which was confirmed to hold in numeric simulations, but I'm curious how to show it more rigorously:

Given $x\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, define $y=Ax$ for invertible $d\times d$ matrix $A$ and consider 2 solutions of this system:

1. Exact solution $x=A^{-1}y$
2. Approximate solution $\hat{x}=A^T y$

We seek to show that angle between two solutions $\cos \angle$ converges in probability to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ where
$$\cos \angle=\frac{\langle x, \hat{x}\rangle}{\|x\|\|\hat{x}\|}$$

and $A$ is a large matrix with IID Gaussian entries.

Proof parts:

1. Define "effective rank" of a matrix $A$ as $R(A)=\|A\|_F^4/\|AA^T\|_F^2$ and show convergence in probability w.r.t. random $x$

\begin{equation}
\cos \angle \xrightarrow{P} \sqrt{\frac{R(A)}{d}}
\tag{0}
\label{0}
\end{equation}

2. Show that $R(A)\xrightarrow{P} d/2$ for large Gaussian matrix $A$
3. Combine these two to get convergence in probability with respect to both random $x$ and $A$

## Part 1

We are interested in $E_x cos\angle$, and for that we distribute "expectation into the expression". Specifically, must show that

\begin{equation}
E_x \cos\angle = E_x \frac{\langle x, \hat{x}\rangle}{\|x\|\|\hat{x}\|}\xrightarrow{P} \frac{E_x \langle x, \hat{x}\rangle}{\sqrt{E_x\|x\|^2}\sqrt{E_x \|\hat{x}\|^2}}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}

The last equality appears to hold in simulations, why?

Earlier [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431036/does-e1-f-oversetd-to-1-ef-for-operatornametrh-1-operatornametrh?noredirect=1&_gl=1*k6aqxr*_ga*MjE5NzQ0ODg5LjE2NTAzMjYxNDU.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTcwODIwNzM2Ny4xMzk3LjEuMTcwODIwOTEyMy4wLjAuMA..#comment1109319_431036) on mathoverflow gave this hint:

[image]

Now we can analyze three expectations separately:

1. $E_x \langle x, \hat{x}\rangle = \|A\|^2_F$
2. $E_x \|x\|^2=d$
3. $E_x \|\hat{x}\|^2=\|AA^T\|_F^2$

Substituting 1,2,3 into $\eqref{1}$ and applying definition of $R(A)$ gets intended result

Proofs of 1,2,3 use trace cyclical property + linearity of trace/expectation which let us switch their order: $E_x\|x\|^2=E \operatorname{Tr} x^T x=E \operatorname{Tr} x x^T =\operatorname{Tr} E x x^T =\operatorname{Tr} I=d$

## Part 2

When $A$ is random matrix with IID standard normal entries we have

1. $E_A\|A\|^2_F=d^2$
2. $E\|AA^T\|_F^2=d^2+2 d^3$ (proof technique by Sangchul Lee [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4818479/998), table of related formulas [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-gaussian-second-moment.nb)

If we can somehow use concentration to change the order of expectation and division, we would get the following

$$R(A)=\frac{\|A\|_F^4}{\|AA^T\|_F^2}\xrightarrow{P} \frac{(E\|A\|_F^2)^2}{E\|AA^T\|_F^2}=\frac{d^4}{d^2+2d^3}$$

Plugging this into $\eqref{0}$ we get

$$E_x[\cos \angle]\xrightarrow{P} \frac{d^4}{d^3+2d^4}= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: This is not a correct proof

Comment: @Kroki indeed, there are a few holes, have an idea how to fix?